# What does "replaces versions" means in .NET Framework terms?

Tags: .net, windows, .net-4.7

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#Release_history) says that the .NET Framework 4.7 replaces versions 4.0–4.6.2. Does this mean that I can run a program that requires (for example) .NET Framework 4.0 with only .NET Framework 4.7 installed?

Comment: It means that it is backwards compatible with any previously released 4.x version.  So yes.

Answer (score 5):

That means that 4.7 is a drop in replacement for 4.0–4.6.2.

For example, if you installed .net 2.0 on a system that already had .net 1.0 you would end up with two instances of .net: 1.0 & 2.0.

If you install .net 4.7 on a system that has .net 4.6 only, then you would only have one .net version on that system, which would be .net 4.7.  The 4.6 .net files are updated to their 4.7 equivalents.